# VPN connect to Postgres DB error

Tags: database, postgresql, vpn, postgresql-9.1, navicat

I have a big trouble: I need connect to my db in another city with Navicat (or other SQL clients). I made vpn - tunnel, but when I connect (with Navicat or other SQL clients) I get the following error

> could not translate host name "ip"  to address: Unknown host

Please help, what I need to do to fix this?

This happens with HeidiSQL, Navicat etc.

Comment: Looks like a configuration issue, DNS? Can you provide more information, configuration-settings?

Comment: What kind of information You mean? If we talk 'bout tools i use OpenVPN and (for VPN tunnel) and 5432 port for connect to BD.
Server configuration i dont know, but can ask 'bout this, say please what kind of information need to.

Comment: Your openvpn-settings, your OS. If you can post them some may be able to help.

Comment: My OS - Windows 8.1, OpenVPN tunnel work pretty well (or specify, please, what kind of configuration we need). 
For DB i have correct name/password/db_name/host name. IP pinged well from server.

Comment: It appears to be a DNS-nameresolution issue. It can't translate the host "ip" into an ip-address. So if you can ping the host you can put this in your /etc/hosts file.

Comment: My bad - i havnt host name - i have ip adress.

Comment: Can you ping the remote host?

Comment: Yes i can (well pinged).